# useEffect's cleanup function doesn't get invoked upon closing the app in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

In my React Native app, I'm trying to stop watching for location updates and stop the foreground service in the `useEffect`'s `cleanup` function when the user closes the app completely.

```
// Start the location foreground service and track user location upon screen mount
useEffect(() => {
  getLocationUpdates(watchId, dispatch);

  // Stop the service upon unmount
  return () => stopLocationUpdates(watchId);
}, []);
```

The problem is that this cleanup function never gets called.

I'm using React Navigation and using [`useFocusEffect`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/) does invoke the cleanup function but I don't want to invoke it upon navigating to other screens. (Just want it to be invoked when the app gets fully closed).

Is there any way to achieve this with `useEffect` or `useMemo`?

Comment: I believe if the app gets fully closed, any service running using app will also stop unless you have background app permissions

Comment: Yeah that's the thing indeed. I'm using [react-native-foreground-service](https://github.com/voximplant/react-native-foreground-service) to be able to track location but want that service to stop when closing the app.

Comment: Its impossible to run a code when app is getting terminated by user. React Native does not support it. You can look into native android/ios code however. If you want to detect whether app is in background or foreground you can use AppState

Comment: AppState won't listen for app close. My only option is to manipulate android native code. In iOS none of these problems exists.